# PDO rowCount() with SELECT mysql, why does one work and not the other?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have 3 different queries, some work and some don't.

I know pdo select does not work with mysql so why do these work?

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = ?");
$q -> execute(array($user['id']));
echo $q -> rowCount();
```

Returns correct data, If I add another param it doesn't,

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = ? && age = 12");
$q -> execute(array($user['id']));
echo $q -> rowCount();
```

It fails returning zero, again this query works and correctly displays the rows matched;

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE id = ? && username = ? && logCount = -1");
$q -> execute(array($user['id'], $user['username']));
```

Why do some work and others don't?

```
echo $q -> rowCount();
```

Comment: Maybe because the second query *indeed* does not return any valid rows? Have you tried executing the query in a MySQL client such as MySQL Query Browser or on the command line, and asserted that the query should *indeed* return accounts where the id **AND** the age both match?

Comment: No it definetely returns 100%;

Answer (score 1):

As per the fine manual, [rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) is defined only for DML queries: `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE`. The manual states that `SELECT` queries are "not guaranteed for all databases" and in fact MySQL support is not reliable.

Comment: What is with the downvotes? This might not be the answer the OP wants to hear, but it is the right answer to the question. He is misunderstanding what the rowCount() function does.

Answer (score -2):

Second query either fails with error or just unable to find rows to match WHERE condition.
To reveal the first cause, add this line to connection code.

```
$dbc->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```